# how to reverse a string data to show it read backwards C++

Tags: c++

i am trying to reverse my string  so it reads the name backwards from were the comment is. i will be setting it above the print i just need to reverse it after its printed the first time
int num = 1;

```
while (num > 0 && num < 2) {
    num = 1;

    string first = "chicken";
    string last = "salad";
    string full = "chicken salad";
    
    string phone = "1";
    string social = "1";

    cout << "enter your first name: ";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "enter your last name: ";
    cin >> last;
    full = first + " " + last;
    

    while (phone.length() != 10) {
            cout << "enter 10 digit phone number (with no dashes or parenthesis): ";
            cin >> phone;
    }
    
        while (social.length() != 9) {
            cout << "enter 9 digit snn (with no dashes or parenthesis): ";
            cin >> social;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "your full name is: " << full << endl;
// i need this one to read dalas nekcihc and i only need to know the command to make it do that. the command will replace this comment
        cout << "your reversed full name is: " << full << endl; 
        cout << "your phone number: ";
        phone.insert(0, "(");
        phone.insert(4, ")");
        phone.insert(8, "-");
        cout << phone << endl;
        cout << "your social security number: ";
        social.insert(5, "-");
        social.insert(3, "-");
        cout << social;
        

    


    cout << "\n\tT H A N K  Y O U\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Ok, you described your task as reversing a string in some way. What is your technical, ***specific*** C++ question?

Comment: i need to reverse the full string for example if full was jacob then i would need to be reversed to show bocaj

Comment: I understand that's what you need to do, but ***what is your specific C++ question***? If I don't know how to replace a tire on my car, I would ask "what tool do I need to take the flat tire off my car", instead of just explaining "I need to go to the store".

Comment: Consider using [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Comment: ok so the tool would be full.(something) to change the full string into reverse i just need to know what command inside the paratheses would accomplish this    ok so the assignmet view i was shown was in that section it should show your full name is :jodi foster; endl; your reversed full name is: retsof idoj

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you -

```
string reverse(string str)
{
    int k = str.length();
    for (int j = 0; j < k / 2; j++)
    {
        swap(str[j], str[k - j - 1]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

I have been using that for long.
Define that function on top of main method and make sure that you have included iostream with `using namespace std;` statement after it.
Pass in a string and it will return the reversed one!

Comment: ok thank you for sending me this this worked almost perfectly it was saying it was expecting ; before the { but after i removed everything the {}, return str and string reverse(string str) it worked perfectly im not sure if its because of my software or what but this really helped me so thank you